# Renderização condicional no React através de tecla!

Tags: javascript, react, javascript-eventos

Olá! Estou com problemas para renderizar um background em um componente react. Tudo que eu preciso é criar uma tela azul que tome um jogo unity rodando através do WebGL por inteiro quando o usuário teclar "M". Abaixo meu código até dado momento;

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.key === "m") {
        return (
            <div className={GameStyles.mapContainer}>
                <span>Aqui um dia terá um mapa!</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Eu já testei a função e aparentemente está funcionando, pois, quando ponho um "console.log("Apertei m")" o console emite esta mensagem, entretanto na hora de renderizar a div com o background nada ocorre. O que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score -1):

Da forma que foi declarado, estão sendo retornados os elementos na função addEventListener, a maneira correta seria controlar se a key 'M' está pressionada ou não através de um estado, algo assim:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [isMKeyPressed, setIsMKeyPressed] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", e => setIsMKeyPressed(e.key === 'm'));
  },[]);

  return (
  <div className={isMKeyPressed ? 'classe-que-define-cor' : ''}>
    <span>Aqui um dia terá um mapa!</span>
  </div>);
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).